# Ionic 3 compare Input-data with json-data doesnt work

Tags: ionic3

i´m new with ionic and i want to do a simple quiz-app with different questiontypes. (btw sorry for my bad englisch :-) )

I struggle atm with following problem: I have a questiontype where the competitor have to input a answer. When he/she clicks the button, the input-answer should be compare with the solution from a json file.

So my Problem is now the input-answer doesnt compare to the answer from the json file. What can i do?

question.ts

```
answerInput: string;

  submitAnswer(answer, question) {
     console.log(this.answerInput);
     if (this.answerInput === question.answer) { 
         this.score = this.score + this.counter;
         this.nextSlide();
     }
     else {
         this.counter = this.counter - this.counterReduce;

    }
    this.counter = this.counter;
   }
```

question.html

```
<div *ngIf="question.questiontype == 'Input'">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input name="answerInput" [(ngModel)]="answerInput"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-label>Your Answer: {{answerInput}}!</ion-label>
    <button ion-button round small(click)="submitAnswer(answer,question)">Look if its true!</button>
```

question.json

```
  {
  "questiontype": "Input",
  "questionText": "A Question like whatever??",
  "hinweis": "Du Depp weißt auch gar nix!",
  "answers": [{
    "answer": "330",
    "correct": true,
    "clicked": false
  }]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is wrong:

if (this.answerInput === question.answer) {

should be

if (this.answerInput === question.answers.answer) {